# Changing title & add Breadcrumbs

Tags: title, breadcrumb

Im wondering the possibilities of making the title of a page change depending how the user got there? For example, if they are on the homepage and make a search, would it be possible to display what they searched for as the title on just on the results page? also how i would add a breadcrumb under the title for users to see where they came from ect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing we are talking about the tab title, if so its possible but not conventional, if is the page title, the code is almost the same and its feasible.

In this last case Wordpress doesn't have a breadcrumb per say, we have to make a custom one, nevertheless Woocommerce has one. If Woocommerce is installed you just need to call the function woocommerce_breadcrumb();  in your php file where that pages load.

if you don't have woocommerce we have to make a custom one. I do not have any at this moment.

Comment: Hi, so yeah i wish to even add another piece of text / heading with the text that i want to change due to whatever has been searched. Example. on the home page if someone searches "food" location "barrow" on the search result page id like for whatever they searched for to display in text below a breadcrumb, i hope that makes sense. Thank you very much for the reply.